# what does ' but so too' mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

I came across the following sentence on the BBC new.

> China's headline annual economic growth numbers are important to the
>   rest of the world - but so too are other monthly economic data as they
>   can provide a more in-depth look at the economy and where it's
>   heading.

I am wondering what 'but so too' means. Does that mean monthly economic data is more important than annual economic growth numbers?

Comment: Related question, [Why do you say “so do I”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/why-do-you-say-so-do-i) and [So do I ( what word type is “so” functioning as?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299173/so-do-i-what-word-type-is-so-functioning-as) and [Is “so” a pronoun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19394/is-so-a-pronoun).

Comment: Also related (and possibly duplicate): [Function of 'too' in the phrase 'so too' or 'so, too'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/function-of-too-in-the-phrase-so-too-or-so-too).

Answer (score 2):

It means that **not only** the headline annual economic growth numbers of China are important to the rest of the world -  China's other monthly economic data is important to the rest of the world **too**.

---

China's annual economic growth numbers **and** other monthly economic data are **all** important to the rest of the world.

---

China's annual economic growth numbers are important to the rest of the world **and so are** China's other monthly economic data.

Answer (score 0):

"So", in here, refers to "important to the rest of the world". Then it simply means both are equally important.